# JS or JQuery drawing recomendation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drawing

i need to do some free hand drawing on my application, the idea is to have a base image where the users will draw on it. then i need to send the image back to my server.

what i need it to do is:

some basic color selection
background/template image
brush size 
undo/redo
the most minimalist user interface possible

which library/solution can u recommend?
`html5/jquery/jqgrid` prefered

iv been looking for some libraries but non seems to be what im looking for

Comment: Check out drawingboard.js - https://github.com/Leimi/drawingboard.js

Comment: it does looks like a nice choose, u think there will be a way to add an image as background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/Leimi/drawingboard.js allows you to set a background image, when initializing the board:

```
var myBoard = new DrawingBoard.Board('container-id', {
    background: 'path/to/image.png'
});
```

See examples here - http://leimi.github.io/drawingboard.js/